# MySQL return prioritizes value else return other value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table (This is a mock-table),

```
+------------+------+--------+
|    Name    | Code | Active |
+------------+------+--------+
| Sales      |   55 |      1 |
| Sales      |   55 |      0 |
| IT         |   22 |      1 |
| Production |   33 |      1 |
| Production |   33 |      0 |
| Marketing  |   77 |      0 |
| Marketing  |   77 |      0 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

And I want to return a list of distinct names and codes. However, I want to determine if the department is active or not. so if Sales has a `1` in active and a `0` in active they are active, but is they had only zeros then they are not.

I've tried a variety of methods and read through a few dozen SO post, but am not gaining any progress.

The output I am trying to achieve is:

```
+------------+------+--------+
|    Name    | Code | Active |
+------------+------+--------+
| Sales      |   55 |      1 |
| IT         |   22 |      1 |
| Production |   33 |      1 |
| Marketing  |   77 |      0 |
+------------+------+--------+
```

How can I prioritize the `Active` column to a value of `1`, but still return an entry if all entries with the same code have a value of `0` (such as marketing)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` name and code and get the maximum value of Active. (Assuming 0 and 1 are the possible values for Active column)

```
SELECT Name,Code,MAX(Active) active
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Name,Code
```

Comment: Oh wow, I can't believe I didn't puzzle that out myself. `MAX` makes perfect sense here.

Comment: @DouglasGaskell We all get those "palm to forehead" moments.  +1